# Emacs keybindings for textboxes in firefox?

Tags: firefox, emacs

I'm so used to emacs that sometimes, when I'm typing something in a textbox in firefox, I sometimes try and do C-p to move up a line. It is *seriously* annoying to have to cancel a print dialog box every time I try and move about my text. If it's not horrendously complicated, I'd like to have keybindings that emulate emacs inside textboxes in firefox...

Obviously, I wouldn't need all the keybindings, but movement, marking, killing and yanking would be useful.

Is this an insane request?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this an insane request?

No! :-)

You can install the **[[image] Firemacs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4141/)** addon to get emacs keybindings in Firefox:

[image]

There's also a rather technical [article on MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Emacs_Keybindings_(Firefox)) on how to enable Emacs-style key bindings for Firefox via GTK. Both work very well, but I recommend the extension since it's so easy to install.

Comment: Nice, although `C-k` goes weird on this site, because it is also the `add code` shortcut...

Answer (score 4):

To set emacs keybinding for *all* GTK based applications execute the following:

```
# legacy
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme Emacs --type string

# modern / e.g. 12.04
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Emacs"
```

See also [Emacs Keybindings - Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Emacs_Keybindings_%28Firefox%29)

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be [Conkeror](http://conkeror.org). Based on its [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conkeror), "Conkeror is a Mozilla-based web browser designed to be navigated primarily by a computer keyboard. Its design is mainly patterned after the text editor GNU Emacs, with some influence from other programs, including vi."

I haven't actually used it so I can't recommend its quality, I've only heard of it. Might be something to check out though.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the ["It's all text"](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) add-on which allows you to edit textareas
with your favorite editor. The add-on displays a small button labeld "edit" at
the bottom of each textarea. When you press it, the editor you have configured
(emacs) will be launched with a temporary file. When you save the file, its contents
are transfered to the textarea. Really helpful for e. g. long wiki pages -- and you will have the complete, real emacs with all your customizations, not just an emulation of some of its keybindings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in having emacs keybindings everywhere in Gnome 3.x, you could change a few properties with gconf-editor, do a few hacks as listed in http://www.c0le.org/2011/10/emacs-keybindings-in-gnome-evolution-3x.html to get it done. Even I find myself pressing C-a and C-e in a lot of non-emacs applications