# How to get Emacs keybindings in Firefox using Mate?

Tags: mate, gtkrc

I have the following line in my `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file:

```
gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"
```

And that works fine in Firefox and e.g. gnome-charachter-map if I use Gnome Classic to log in. Pressing
ctrl-a in this text field sends the cursor to the start of the line as
expected. If I use Mate installed from the 12.04 repository on
mate-desktop.org then the emacs keybindings are not honored. Ctrl-a selects
all text.

I think that the .gtkrc-2.0 file is read for some mate applications - mate-terminal seems to understand `gtk-keynav-wrap-around = 0`, for example.

The [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20748/emacs-keybindings-for-textboxes-in-firefox) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57207/rebind-control-n-control-p) that suggest using 3rd party programs seem a bit 
flakey. Is there a better way to get mate to use .gtkrc-2.0 and in particular the emacs key bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the link:
http://lwn.net/Articles/509467/
The relevant command is:

```
mateconftool-2 -s /desktop/mate/interface/gtk_key_theme -t string Emacs
```